# ActiveRecord find() only seems to work with symbol arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building a new Rails app against an existing database. I have one model so far that looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'user'
  self.primary_key = 'name'
end
```

When i hop into the console and try `User.find("Bob")` and get

```
User Load (23.4ms)  SELECT  `user`.* FROM `user` WHERE `user`.`name` = '--- !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::StatementCache::Substitute {}\n' LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'name'=Bob
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:155:in `find'
        from (irb):3
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Trying `User.find('Bob')` gets me the same thing.

If i try `User.find(:Bob)` i get back the right record.

This also means that controllers and routes generated by rake don't work, going to `localhost:3030/users/bob` gets me

> ```
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
> Couldn't find User with 'name'=bob
> ```

I cannot alter the database, so adding a key or changing the existing primary key is not an option.

Am i missing an obvious model component or database setting?

Comment: I would recommend using the standard numeric ids and using `User.find(name: 'Bob')`. Both because of the principle of least surprise and the fact that thing start getting really messy once you mess with PKs. If you want to use the name in url use something like https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: @papirtiger, it's `User.find_by(name: 'Bob')`, not `User.find(name: 'Bob')`

Comment: Is the user's name used as a foreign key somewhere? If not you may want to start using a numeric primary key as suggested by others.

Comment: I don't know how to fix that, but if symbols work, why not use that? You can convert strings to symbols using `.to_sym`.

Comment: oops, I meant `find_by`.

Comment: "why not use that?" because you really shouldn't  - the short version is: A) there is more than one 'Bob' in the world yes? uniqueness is a Real Problem B) meaningful keys always change, and that is very painful. You think your name is aways going to be the same? not for other people. People change their names, addresses, and everything else. You can't rely on that AND YOU DONT NEED TO.

Comment: The primary key of a table should be a unique identifier that never changes... it's for internal representation of a unique row of a table- it doesn't have to be meaningful to an end user - you can create a meaningful slug for that out of meaningful data, while still retaining the integer id. Here's a quick article on messing with primary keys eg: http://joshsymonds.com/blog/2012/03/04/dont-mess-with-primary-keys/

Comment: I get the feeling that the question either isn't being read correctly or perhaps the poor state of the database is being underestimated. I think @Mischa isn't advocating for using names but rather for using symbols as the arguments. Believe me when i say that if i could use numeric IDs i would do so in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 1):

To build on @papirtiger's comment, I would suggest you eliminate:

```
self.table_name = 'user'    # this is the default table name already
self.primary_key = 'name'   # stick with PK ID generated in migration
```

Then, in your console, you can use commands like:

```
>> find_by(name: 'Bob')
```

and many others as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object).

Comment: Actually the recommended way seems to be `find_by(name: 'Bob')`

Comment: Also, he's working with an existing database that apparently uses the user's name as primary key, so he cannot "stick with PK ID generated in migration". He could start using a numeric primary key, but that may be difficult if the `user.name` is used as a foreign key elsewhere.

Comment: Altering the tables is not an option, so i'm stuck with the name and key. Also, my concern isn't the console as much as it is having rake generated routes work. I'll update my question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i want to admit to this level of numbskullery, but it turns out that the issue was

UPPERCASE_COLUMN_NAMES

All i needed to do was

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'user'
  self.primary_key = 'NAME'
end
```

I'm still curious as to why symbol arguments worked at all, but for the time being my issue is resolved. I mean, i still have the issue of being a knucklehead, but at least my models work.